# Why does Android Studio fail to build when accessing a ViewStub through ViewDataBinding?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-databinding

I have a layout defined that contains 2 `ViewStubs`. They are defined as follows:

```
<ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/top_divider_stub"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/top_divider_layout"
        android:layout="@layout/include_line_separator_horizontal"/>

<ViewStub
        android:id="@+id/bottom_divider_stub"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inflatedId="@+id/bottom_divider_layout"
        android:layout="@layout/include_line_separator_horizontal"/>
```

In my adapter, I'm trying to access the `ViewStub` through the ViewDataBinding generated by the DataBinding library, in my case it's `TitleBinding`. Attempting to do the following causes an error.

```
TitleBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(view);
ViewStub topDividerStub = binding.topDividerStub;
ViewStub bottomDividerStub = binding.bottomDividerStub;
```

I receive this error and the application fails to compile.

```
Error:(31, 50) error: incompatible types: ViewStubProxy cannot be converted to ViewStub
```

I worked around it by setting the variable to type `ViewStubProxy`, allowing it to compile but giving an incompatible types syntax highlighting error. I'd like to know what the correct way of doing this if possible.

*This works...*

```
ViewStubProxy topDividerStub = binding.topDividerStub;
ViewStubProxy bottomDividerStub = binding.bottomDividerStub;
```

*Resulting in*

[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem. It seems this is a bug of DataBinding. I'm not sure.

Or you can create a ViewStubProxy by yourself:

```
TitleBinding binding = DataBindingUtil.bind(view);

ViewStubProxy viewStubProxy = new ViewStubProxy((ViewStub) view.findViewById(R.id.viewStub));

viewStubProxy.setContainingBinding(binding);
```